# How can I change the caption of the button at the PayPal website? (PayPal Express Checkout)

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, paypal-express

how can I change the button caption at the PayPal website? I read that the caption is depending on the url (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/), but I dont know how I can change this required parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way works for me:

1. copying PayPal config data from core/mage/paypal/model/config.php to local/mage/paypal/model/config.php
2. and commented out line 624: //$params['useraction'] = 'commit';
3. after clearing the cache, the button caption at the PayPal website is "continue"
4. done :)